# Facebook share description missing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I am using the Facebook debugger to check the scraping of my page but the description is always missing.

You can go here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/  and input my page's url http://on.aol.com/video/kit-harington-teases-possible-return-to-got-519083276    And click "fetch new scrap information".

You will see that this page has all expected Open Graph tags and the preview looks like this: 
[image]

But problem is coming!!! When you click the image or the "See this in the share dialog" to open the real share dialog, the description is missing like this:
[image]

I am the admin of the Facebook app for this page so "fetch new scrap information" should have refreshed the cache of this page. But when you click "Fetch existing scrape information", description always missing as well.

For more info, you can directly check http://on.aol.com/video/kit-harington-teases-possible-return-to-got-519083276 or any other video page in http://on.aol.com and click the "Facebook" share button on the left to see it. It would look like below and description still missing!
[image]

Comment: This is not an error on your end; Facebook just sometimes decides to show only the video and not the description. There is nothing you can do about that (apart from maybe filing a bug report, if you think they shouldn’t do it this way – but they will probably just tell you that it is by design.)

Comment: What do you mean "sometimes"?  Really weird that I compared a random video page in Youtube and its description is displayed well in facebook share even it doesn't have a <meta property="og:description"/> tag but a <meta name="description"/> tag instead.

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same problem. All tags are in place, even compared them with YouTube, but videos still displaying without description and title is overlaid as in picture above. Facebook's sharing debugger didn't find any issues with meta tags.

Answer (score 1):

if you can change the code for that page, try ad this tag, i dont see that tag on that page,

```
<meta name="description" content="aaaaaa">
```

that page have og:description but facebook treat that video like normal facebook video (i guess you want to make it look like youtube that have description)

Comment: I tried but issue is still there. Thank you anyway. Youtube use <meta name="description" content="aaaaaa"> instead of <meta property="og: description"/>. Their video works, but mine is still missing.